# How to define a macro globally with a name containing a number?

Tags: grouping, csname

I'm trying to define multiple macros in a \foreach loop. The name of each macro contains a different integer. To do that I use \csname ... \endcsname.

The issue is I would like to be able to call these macros outside the loop. Specifically I'm building a text line by line and I want to store each line in a numbered macro so as to be able to call all of them when I'm done.

Here is what I tried:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}


\begin{document}
\large

\foreach \k in {1,...,3}{
\expandafter\newcommand\csname step\k\endcsname{line n° \k}
\csname step\k\endcsname
%\global\let\csname step\k\endcsname = \csname step\k\endcsname

}
%\csname step1\endcsname

\end{document}
```

I tried to make each macro global using \global\let, but it throws multiple errors:

```
Extra \endcsname
LaTeX Error: Command \csname already defined
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure out what, probably because I don't understand how \csname, \global and \let work.

Comment: `\expandafter\xdef\csname step\k\endcsname{line n° \k}`. (if the definition text contains some that shouldn't expand you will have to protect it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `\global\let\csname step\k\endcsname`, you're redefining `\csname`.

You need

```
\global\expandafter\let\csname step\k\endcsname
```

(because `\global` wants to see `\let`, `\def` or variants after it, so it expands token to this purpose).

On the other hand, you're failing to expand `\k` in the body of the definition, so you're doomed, unless you use `\xdef`.

```
\foreach \k in {1,...,3}{
  \expandafter\xdef\csname step\k\endcsname{\unexpanded{line n° }\k}
}
```

Now `\csname step3\endcsname` would produce “line n° 3”.

I protected with `\unexpanded` everything that's not `\k`, so not to get nasty surprises.

A different approach with `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\nforeach}{mO{1}mm}
 {
  \cs_set_protected:Nn \__funkiephil_nforeach:n { #4 }
  \int_step_function:nnnN { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } \__funkiephil_nforeach:n
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\nforeach{1}{3}{\ExpandArgs{c}\newcommand{step#1}{line n° #1}}

\begin{document}

\csname step1\endcsname

\csname step2\endcsname

\csname step3\endcsname

\end{document}
```

Note that `\ExpandArgs{c}\newcommand{...}` is easier lingo for

```
\expandafter\newcommand\csname...\endcsname
```

but requires a fairly recent (October 2021) release of LaTeX.

The syntax for `\nforeach` is

```
\nforeach{<start>}[<step>]{<end>}{<what to do>}
```

and in `<what to do>` you can use `#1` for the current integer in the loop. The step is optional (and defaults to 1).

[image]

Comment: I can't say I understand everything but it works, thank you